# Replacing strings with changing data

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I've been looking at encryption and long story short, I need to remove an xml tag from a string.

Each string needs a global rule for replacing the string, and I've looked at regex for this, but it doesn't make sense.

Here are some examples

```
<BitStrength>384</BitStrength>

<BitStrength>1024</BitStrength>

<BitStrength>12300</BitStrength>
```

I need to replace the whole string and the number inside as well, with nothing.
I've tried things like:

```
string.replace("<BitStrength>12300</BitStrength>","");
```

But the issue is the length and characters of the number, and a match is never found.
Has anyone got a solution? Maybe regex is the way to go?

PS. Preferably a solution in C#.

EDIT: I'm looking for a solution that replaces the whole string in not only this kind of example but strings in general.

```
<BitStrength>4633</BitStrength>
<BitStrength>336</BitStrength>
!!SomeConstantData!!5437!!EndConstant!!
I would like 2 eggs today.
I would like 17 eggs today.
I would like 258367 eggs today.
```

Now if I put `string.replace("I would like ","").replace(" eggs today.")` I would be left with the number 258367, because I didn't cover this in my statement. I'm looking for a solution to delete this data. It can be any value.

In my particular example I'm looking to replace `<BitStrength>384</BitStrength>` in `<BitStrength>384</BitStrength><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>code</Modulus><Exponent>code</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>`
The Issue I face is that the number between the bitstrength tags can be anything between 386 and 16384, and I need to remove the entire bitstrength string.

Comment: You should use an XML parser.

Comment: I could, but that's like trying to shoot a rabbit with a death machine. I need a simple solution, something like regex, and someone to make sense of it all. I could use an xml parser, but like I said, rabbit, death machine.

Comment: `XElement` is extremely simple.

Comment: @CausticLasagne: I would rather call it *the right tool for the job*. The problem with regexes is that they are a rather messy solution. You could try something along the lines of `<Tag>[^<]*</Tag>`. However, this will only work if there are no other tags nested inside.

Comment: please show a couple of inputs and desired outputs

Comment: @SLaks, great advice, but no one ever seems to provide a concrete answer with an Xml parser; I wonder why?.

Comment: @OmegaMan: Search Google for C# XML parser?

Comment: @SLaks I don't want to use a search engine...why can't someone step up and provide a valid answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = "<BitStrength>384</BitStrength>";
string pattern = @"<BitStrength>\d*</BitStrength>";
string replacement = " ";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
```

returns

```
Original String: <BitStrength>384</BitStrength>
Replacement String:
```

Comment: Admins, you may close this question, no further content.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what you have tried, and I wonder if the failure is because you are not making the pattern string as a literal using the `@` before it?

This example works:

```
Regex.Replace(@"Blah<BitStrength>12300</BitStrength>Blah", 
              @"(\<BitStrength\>12300\</BitStrength\>)", 
              string.Empty)
```

and returns

> BlahBlah

If the actual number does not matter use this pattern:

```
(\<BitStrength\>\d+\</BitStrength\>)
```

Comment: I tried that code and it didn't work. The number characters and length does not matter, the whole string must go, but the numbers keep changing.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
 var source = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                          "<BitStrength>384</BitStrength>", 
                          "<BitStrength>1024</BitStrength>", 
                          "<BitStrength>12300</BitStrength>");

 var result = source.Replace("<BitStrength>12300</BitStrength>", string.Empty);
```